# how to process multiple .gz files via spark streaming?

Tags: spark-streaming

I have been trying to read multiple `.gz` files from hadoop filesystem via spark streaming . Is there any possibility to do that? if yes can you provide me a solution

Answer (score -1):

Spark Streaming process file on the basis of time stamp i.e. only those files were processed which are added to certain path after the start of spark streaming. Spark streaming does not process files which are placed before the start of streaming context.

In simple words Streaming works on live data not on the old ones.